# Purge visual studio from system manually

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

So I thought I'd save myself some time in moving my visual studio installation from an old drive to my C-drive. Turns out this was a very bad idea.

I ended up trying the installers to clean up some of the mess, but they won't work, since they can't find all the files they're supposed to remove. This led me to manually delete the 'Visual studio 1x.0'-folders in an attempt to have the installers show 'Install' versus 'Modify', 'Repair' and 'Uninstall'. Now I've tried to do what support suggests on this page, https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/248697, but no luck...

How can I get the installers to... install.. rather than 'Modify', 'Repair' and 'Uninstall', which they won't do anyway, since some (or most) files are missing?

Suggestions appreciated.

I just want the installer to install on C-drive, and possibly overwrite any remaining trash, be it files or configurations.

Comment: You should try a different uninstaller to clean up the "mess" rather than installing on top of it.

Comment: What do you mean by a 'different uninstaller'?

Comment: Something like [Revo Uninstaller](http://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) may be able to clean up what's remaining.

Comment: Thank you, this worked like a charm :-) If you make this an answer, I'd happily accept it

Comment: Per your request, I've added an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Software uninstallers sometimes fail to clean up completely.  In those instances, a product like [Revo Uninstaller](http://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) should be able to clean up any remaining files and/or registry entries.  It scans for any “leftovers” from a standard uninstaller and gives you the opportunity to selectively remove those objects that are preventing you from reinstalling.