# Visual studio installer retains previous installation path

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

After removing visual studio 2013 and 2015 manually, the installer retains the previous installation path. ([Purge visual studio from system manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33096687/purge-visual-studio-from-system-manually)) The problem is, the previous path points to a drive that I formatted and installed Linux on. In true Microsoft style, the installation path is non-editable, non-browsable...

How do I remove this? I've searched the registry for the string, but nothing more shows up (I've deleted some leftover registries). I have this problem both for VS 2013 and VS 2015

[image: Read only line edit]

Comment: I tried to run /uninstall /force without any luck. Started deleting registry keys manually - don't do that. Use RegScanner as Samuel Caillerie mentions above. Solved my problem.